# Why is my Linq query on a List Dictionary throwing an "unable to cast object' error?

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `Dim dictionaryOfAlertsForSC As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO))`. The dictionary will always have two records. I need to filter out the records based on the key. I am using Linq on the dictionary:

```
lstAlertsForSC = From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO)) In dictionaryOfAlertsForSC Where kv.Key.Contains(ASSESSMENTS) Select kv.Value
```

Where lstAlertForSC is a list of type AlertBo. It's throwing some runtime error of type casting for the select part in the Linq query. Details of exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MA.DMR.HCSIS.Common.AlertsBO]],MA.DMR.HCSIS.Common.AlertsBO]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MA.DMR.HCSIS.Common.AlertsBO]'.
```

Here is my detailed code:

```
 Public Sub GenerateSCAlert(ByVal userInfo As UserInfoType)
    Dim ispAlertProcessDAO As ISPAlertProcessDAO
    Dim lstAlertsForSC As New List(Of AlertsBO)
    Dim dictionaryOfAlertsForSC As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO))
    Dim strAlertBOXML As String
    strAlertBOXML = String.Empty
    Try
        LoggingHelper.Log("----------------------ISP Action based Alert Management process for SC started----------------------", TraceEventType.Information, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), LoggingHelper.ISPProcesses.ISPAlertForSC)
        ispAlertProcessDAO = New ISPAlertProcessDAO(userInfo)
        dictionaryOfAlertsForSC = ispAlertProcessDAO.GenerateSCAlert()
        If (dictionaryOfAlertsForSC.Count > 0) Then
            lstAlertsForSC = From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO)) In dictionaryOfAlertsForSC Where kv.Key.Contains(ASSESSMENTS) Select kv.Value.Single()
            If (lstAlertsForSC.Count > 0) Then
                strAlertBOXML = ispAlertProcessDAO.GenerateXMLForActionBasedAlerts(True, lstAlertsForSC)
```

I am getting an exception where I have applied Linq.

My application is in VB.Net, but C# will also do, if necessary.

Comment: It seems that you are fetching exactly one item. Then you could do `= (From ... Select kv.Value).Single()`.

Comment: You really need the parenthesis as posted in the first comment. If you have the exact key, why not just `dictionaryOfAlertsForSC(ASSESSMENTS)`?

Comment: Please do not vandalize posts, even ones you've made. Content on Stack Overflow is licensed under CC BY-SA (version 2, 3, or 4 depending on when it was posted) when you submit it here, so you relinquish full control at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch an element for a specific key, you can just use the appropriate accessor:

```
lstAlertsForSC = dictionaryOfAlertsForSC(ASSESSMENTS)
```

Your LINQ query

```
From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO)) 
    In dictionaryOfAlertsForSC 
    Where kv.Key.Contains(ASSESSMENTS) 
    Select kv.Value
```

returns an enumerator that can iterate over all results of the query. Of course, the compiler does not know that the query can return only one element. That's why the result is some kind of `IEnumerable(Of List(Of String))`.

There is an extension method for `IEnumerable(Of T)` that fetches a single element. Calling this method on the result of the query gives you the desired list:

```
lstAlertsForSC = 
    (From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO)) 
        In dictionaryOfAlertsForSC 
        Where kv.Key.Contains(ASSESSMENTS) 
        Select kv.Value).Single()
```

If you leave the parentheses away as follows:

```
lstAlertsForSC = 
    From kv As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of AlertsBO)) 
        In dictionaryOfAlertsForSC 
        Where kv.Key.Contains(ASSESSMENTS) 
        Select kv.Value.Single()
```

then the `Single()` method is called on each `kv.Value` and you get ab `IEnumerable(Of String)`. However, this query is likely to fail because the inner lists probably do not contain a single value.